# What is the maximum number of indices one can create on a table with N columns?

Tags: databases, permutations

Say, I have a database table with $N$ columns. What is the (theoretical) maximum number of indices I can create on that table? For $N = 1,2,3$ it's easy enough to calculate the answer $(1, 4, 15)$, but is there any formula? Also, is there a "name" for this number?

Comment: This question is already asked, but on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50025724/10502622

Comment: No, I'm not asking about "useful" indexes, I'm interested in maximum possible number of indexes.

Comment: Where did you get 1,4,15 from?

Comment: @D.W. For 1 column, you can create one index apparently; for 2 columns, you can create indexes on columns 1 & 2 and combinations 1, 2 & 2, 1; and so on..

Comment: That sounds like it will lead to 1, 3, 15, not 1, 4, 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean the following: given $N$ columns, there are

- $N$ single columns, giving $N$ different indices
- $N(N-1)/2$ pairs of columns, and 2 ways to combine each pair, giving $N(N-1)$ different indices
- $\frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{2 \cdot 3}$ triples of columns, and $3 \cdot 2$ ways to combine each triple, giving $N(N-1)(N-2)$ different indices

and so on. This number doesn't have a (well-known) name, but the sequence does have its own [OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A007526):

> Eighteenth- and nineteenth-century combinatorialists call this the number of (nonnull) "variations" of n distinct objects, namely the number of permutations of nonempty subsets of {1,...,n}.

Various formulas are given to compute it, including a recurrence relation $a_n = n(a_{n-1} + 1)$ and the rather surprising $a_n = \lfloor{e \cdot n! - 1}\rfloor$.

One could argue that you can create *more* indices by taking into account that columns can be used in ascending and descending mode. For indices with more than one column, this even has an influence on which records are 'near' each other.